# How can I pull data from realtime firebase database into an array? I wish to change static data in an array to firebase data

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, android-database

I have created a custom calendar which uses an array "HomeCollection" taken from github link https://github.com/DeveloperBrothers/Custom-Calendar-View in order to create a custom calendar in my android application. Currently the Events data is hard-coded into this array (see code snippet below) but wish to take the event attributes from my firebase database instead where I have created a database and saved such Event data (see picture link below).

```js
HomeCollection.date_collection_arr = new ArrayList<HomeCollection>();
        HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-11-21", "Winter Table Quiz", "7-10 pm, Clubhouse", "ClubHouse", "Come along to the Winter Table Quiz, €5pp, tables of 4, theres lots of great prizes to be won."));
       HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-11-03", "u21 Division 1 Training ", "10-11am, Club Grounds", "ClubHouse", "Weekly Division 1 training. Weather dependant."));
        HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-11-03", "u21 Division 2 Training ", "11-12am, Club Grounds", "ClubHouse", "Weekly Division 2 training. Weather dependant."));
        HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-11-10", "u21 Division 1 Training ", "10-11am, Club Grounds", "ClubHouse", "Weekly Division 1 training. Weather dependant."));
        HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-11-10", "u21 Division 2 Training ", "11-12am, Club Grounds", "ClubHouse", "Weekly Division 2 training. Weather dependant."));
        HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-11-17", "u21 Division 1 Training ", "10-11am, Club Grounds", "ClubHouse", "Weekly Division 1 training. Weather dependant."));
        HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-11-17", "u21 Division 2 Training ", "11-12am, Club Grounds", "ClubHouse", "Weekly Division 2 training. Weather dependant."));
        HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-11-24", "u21 Division 1 Training ", "10-11am, Club Grounds", "ClubHouse", "Weekly Division 1 training. Weather dependant."));
        HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-11-24", "u21 Division 2 Training ", "11-12am, Club Grounds", "ClubHouse", "Weekly Division 2 training. Weather dependant."));*/
        cal_month = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        cal_month_copy = (GregorianCalendar) cal_month.clone();
        hwAdapter = new HwAdapter(this, cal_month, HomeCollection.date_collection_arr);
```

Could anyone help me in changing this static code to my Firebase database data?

[Link to my firebase JSON events tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJnGm.jpg)

Comment: What is expected result that you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

So you can make a Java bean for saving all this data. Make `getter` and `setter` methods for all the data that you are storing as an object. For example, make the `getter` and `setter` methods for the objects properties like : eventDate,eventDescription,etc and say you name your bean as `EventBean.java`.

Now use the `childEventListener` like so :

```
mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().getChild("event");
mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new OnChildEventListener(){

@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName){
EventBean data = snapshot.getValue(EventBean.class);//now you have got data in the 
eventbean instance
System.out.println(data.getEventDate());
}
});
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1) you have to get the firebase data reference in your code

```
DatabaseReference mFireBaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

2) then you have add the firebase listener to get the data:

```
mFireBaseDatabaseReference.child("events").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                //you can parse the data in your models here like this
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
Event event = childSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(event);
}
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: you can follow the firebase android documentation to know more about firebase realtimedatabase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: I recieve an error when using the above code but it gave me the idea of the following code:

Comment: mFireBaseDatabaseReference.child("events").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Event event = childSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                    HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection(event.getEventDate(),event.getEventName(),event.getEventTime(),event.getEventLocation(),event.getEventDescription()));
                }

Comment: but event.getTime() etc doesnt seem to pull the data from firebase into the array